# Why are my Chrome extensions crashing every time I start the browser or in the middle of browsing?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm using Chrome Version: 41.0.2272.89 m. Some of my Chrome extensions (on Windows 7) crash every time I start the browser or sometimes in the middle of browsing.

The message that is shown in the chrome://extensions page under the crashed extension is

> "This extension may have been corrupted."

There appears an option to "Repair" the extension just left to the bin (remove) icon.

[image][Large size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCWxx.png)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is every extension doing it or just clearly?

Comment: No, several extensions. Including Adblock Plus, Neater bookmarks etc. I have a way around this problem for those extensions though. I downloaded the CRX files, and installed them in developer mode. However, for some weird reason, Clearly gets broken if I install it that way.